# react with webpack federation plugin: why load react twice?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-module-federation

probably I have a conceptual error regarding Module Federation. What I am trying to do is create a "shared project" (reactcore) that loads react, react-dom, MUI, etc, but not any specific UI. and the other UI's  (diverse widgets) that I want to load will reuse the react and other dependencies offered by the core (use the core just as a library provider).

what I got is that if load both scripts (mpreactcore and mpwidgets, the one with the UI) it works, but react and react-core are being loaded TWICE.

[![screenshot][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXEYB.png

I am wondering if I am trying to use Module Federation the wrong way. perhaps it is mandatory that the "core" should be a "shell" and all the other widgets should be injected in the shell, for example, passing a parameter when creating a single App component? my approach is due to the fact that my widgets are loosely coupled, more like a library of utilitarian widgets rather than a massive unified UI.
thanks for your recommendations.